# java - How to get max ID in SQL

Tags: java, mysql, methods

It Takes Too Long For Me To Create And Send `PreparedStatement`'s or `ResultSet`.

How Can I Get MaxID From SQL in Java Method?

Writed this but not working...

```
private static int getLastId()
{   
    int returned=0;

    try
    {
        PreparedStatement stat;
        ResultSet rs;
        String sql="select max(id) from home";
        stat=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=stat.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            returned = rs.getInt("id")+1;// just want a new id for new person
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(""+e);
    }
    return returned;
}
```

I Tried To Use It Like This...

```
                //reseting every thing and get lastId+1;
                System.out.println("added");
                field_name.setText("");
                field_pass.setText("");
                int temp= getLastId();
                field_id.setText(""+temp);
```

But It Returns 0!
I Don't Have any SQL error.

Did I Use It Wrong?
or ?

Thanks For Help.

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530108/java-resultset-using-max-sql-function

Comment: thanks, but..., can i write this code in link, in my method? then,how to call method? is my method calling is right?

Comment: You can retrieve the maximum ID value from a table. But, you MUST NOT use that value to determine the id of a row you're about to insert unless you are SURE that only one running program is inserting rows that way. If you're not sure why, please read about race conditions.

Comment: thanks for your advice, i try to read it but... i can't understand English very well! i tried some searches, it gives too many useful information but very complicate for me to understand, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems here, one of which is that in your current code you aren't actually accessing the `max(id)` which you put in the query.  One way around this is to assign an alias:

```
PreparedStatement stat;
ResultSet rs;
String sql = "SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM home";
stat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = stat.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    returned = rs.getInt("max_id") + 1;
}
```

This fixes the syntax problem, but there is still the problem of whether this is the best way to get the next `id`.  I would recommend that you switch to using an auto increment column, which MySQL will manage for you.  Then, you don't need to worry about keeping track of the latest ID value.  In fact, you don't even need to specify a value when inserting; the database will handle this for you.

Comment: Thank you very much it works, can i use this code in my method? is there any issue in calling method? for your suggestion i used auto increment in my id column, but just don't know how to return the (last one +1), is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Why do you need the id in the first place if you have an auto increment column?  My best advice here would be to avoid this situation where you even need to rush back to the database to figure out what happened.

Comment: i thought it looks more efficient if the lastID is checked from the database.